# Logistic map confusion

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Logistic map is a simple example of discrtete dynamical systems defined as $$x_{i+1}=\lambda*x_{i}*(1-x_{i}).$$
It is known that for $\lambda=4$ this map shows a chaotic behavior for $x\in (0,1)$.

The question:

How could it be that the logistic map at $\lambda=4$ is chaotic, while,  starting with $x_0=0.5$, the iteration goes to 1 then fixed at 0?

Comment: This is a very special starting point.

Comment: @Peter I think the chaos should appear for any starting point in (0,1).

Comment: It's a misunderstanding that *every* orbit of a chaotic system must be “random-looking”. Se for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Finding_cycles_of_any_length_when_r_=_4, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory#Density_of_periodic_orbits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaotic maps may still have fixed points and periodic orbits. What distinguishes a chaotic map is that points that start out close together quickly diverge from one another - this is called "sensitive dependence on initial conditions".

For the logistic map $x_{i+1}=4x_i(1-x_i)$ the sequence $\{x_i\}$for an initial value $x_0=0.5$ is, as you say,

$\{0.5, 1, 0, 0, \dots \}$

but for $x_0=0.51$ we get the sequence

$\{0.51, 0.996, 0.00159936, 0.00637208, 0.025385647, \dots \}$

and for $x_0=0.52$ we get the sequence

$\{0.52, 0.9984, 0.00638976, 0.025395724, 0.099003124 \dots \}$

and by the time we get to $x_{10}$ the two sequences are completely different:

[image]

Contrast this with the behaviour when $\lambda=2$, when $x_{i+1}=2x_i(1-x_i)$:

$\{0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, \dots \} \\
\{0.51, 0.4998, 0.49999992, 0.5, \dots \} \\
\{0.52, 0.4992, 0.49999872, 0.5, \dots \}$

when initial points that start close to $0.5$ all rapidly converge to the fixed point $0.5$.

Comment: (+1) for mentioning the property "sensitive to the initial conditions" , which we also have in physics in the chaos theory.

Comment: [+1] Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is actually meant with "chaotic" is that almost all start values lead to a (theoretically) non-periodical sequence and the sequence shows no structure which means that it can be used as a pseudo-random-generator.

Comment: I think that any start value should lead to a non- periodic sequence. If it is as you said, then it will show structure (periodicity) in our case.

Comment: If you pick up a random number as a start value, the probability will be $1$ that the sequence will be chaotic. The idea of the logistic map is not that every start value does the job. Perhaps, if we take $3.8$ instead of $4$, we can remove your problem, but I am still sceptical.

Comment: alright, thanks much